# Error with httpd config on Centos

Tags: apache, centos

When I try to restart httpd using 'service httpd restart' I get the following error:

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 10 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-directories.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I'm running Centos 6 with apache 2.2

I didn't change anything to my httpd-directories.conf, and I read that Order is valid command and that there might be a problem with my configuration elsewhere, but I don't know where to look. Any suggestions?

The beginning of my httpd-directories.conf file:

```
<Directory />
 Options All
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /home>
 AllowOverride All
 Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNoExec +Includes
 <Limit GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Limit>
 <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
 </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

Comment: - Make sure "mod_access_compat.so" module is loaded in you configuration something like below : "LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so"

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `httpd.conf` and make sure that [`mod_authz_host`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) module is loaded.

[How to enable/install Apache Modules ?](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/apache-2-web-server-on-centos-6#install-apache-modules)

Comment: I added "LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so" to my httpd.conf and now I get a new error:
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-php-handlers.conf:
Invalid command 'AddHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 0):

It was not a good idea to edit my httpd.conf. I got a new error from adding this code to my httpd.conf
    `LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so`

What solved my problem was the code below

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build update
./build apache
./build rewrite_confs
```

Comment: So you disabled `mod_authz_host` again ?